# If else using case for returning value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do an if else statement using `CASE`. If no records, then make it `0` then `+1`. Or else, just take the last record then `+1`. At first try i used `ISNULL(statement,0)`. But it doesn't have else statement.

Then I saw many other examples on StackOverflow for a case statement, but I don't seem to understand how to implement it

```
INSERT INTO TICKET_SALES (
    TRXDATE, 
    KIOSKID, 
    BOOKINGREFERENCENUM, 
)
VALUES (
    '2019-01-18 16:59:29',
    'KIOSK1',
    ((SELECT TOP 1 BOOKINGREFERENCENUM FROM TICKET_SALES ORDER BY BOOKINGREFERENCENUM DESC)+1),
);
```

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-identity/

Comment: To insert values from a query use `INSERT .. SELECT` instead of `INSERT .. VALUES`

Comment: Also, *DON'T* use `MAX + 1` as an ID. This guarantees duplicates and invalid relations if a row gets deleted. You can end up with a new row referencing records related to the *old* deleted row

Comment: Careful with a solution like thatl it can very easily suffer from race conditions; which could mean 2 rows have the same ID. Personally, as @jarlh suggested, I would use `IDENTITY`; however to doesn't mean you will have sequential numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use expressions to supply values, you can change `VALUES` for `SELECT`, although you will only be able to supply 1 row with `SELECT` (unless you use `UNION ALL`).

```
INSERT INTO TICKET_SALES (
    TRXDATE, 
    KIOSKID, 
    BOOKINGREFERENCENUM
)
SELECT
    '2019-01-18 16:59:29',
    'KIOSK1',
    1 + ISNULL(
        (SELECT TOP 1 BOOKINGREFERENCENUM FROM TICKET_SALES ORDER BY BOOKINGREFERENCENUM DESC),
        0)
```

Please be ware of using this type of "tricks" to generate IDs, as others pointed out, it's a **very bad idea** (check StepUp's answer to know how to correct).

Comment: lol. how did i miss out combination of 1+ isnull(). FYI, i need those values not to create ids as there are many rows with null. So i just want to increment if there is any exisitng record with booking reference number for specific condition in php

Comment: @KIRPALSINGH be careful of race conditions then. If you run this code multiple times in parallel it will most likely generate the same `BOOKINGREFERENCENUM` more than once. You can solve this with `IDENTITY` columns or creating a `SEQUENCE` and retrieve its next value, only if you see the need to.

Comment: Do accept as answer if any of it worked for you. It will help others to find working solution quickly. @KIRPALSINGH

Answer (score 1):

Just create table with `Idetitity(1, 1)`:

```
CREATE table TicketSales
(
       TrxDate DATETIME
    ,  KioskId INT
    , BookingReferenceNum int IDENTITY(1,1)
)
```

[As MSDN says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017)

> Identity columns can be used for generating key values. The identity
>   property on a column guarantees the following:
>
> - Each new value is generated based on the current seed & increment.
> - Each new value for a particular transaction is different from other
>     concurrent transactions on the table.
> - The identity property on a column does not guarantee the following:
> - Uniqueness of the value - Uniqueness must be enforced by using a
>     PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint or UNIQUE index.
>
> [... to further read](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: thanks, but you didnt understand my question. i am not trying to create id's here. Anyway someone posted the answer below

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way IMO would be to declare variable to hold desired value, assign value to it in easy-to-read way, and then use it in `INSERT` statement.

Moreover, no need to takke `TOP 1` with ordering, just use `MAX` function :)

```
DECLARE @id INT;
SELECT @id = CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE MAX(BOOKINGREFERENCENUM) + 1 END
FROM MyTable;

INSERT INTO TICKET_SALES (
    TRXDATE, 
    KIOSKID, 
    BOOKINGREFERENCENUM, 
)
VALUES (
    '2019-01-18 16:59:29',
    'KIOSK1',
    @id
);
```

**NOTE**: you are reinventing the wheel, SQL has something like `IDENTITY`, it's good for this kind of task.